# Flash For Iphone Scrollable List component

Tags: flash, components

I am making a IPhone App with Flash and need a scrollable list component that would preferably scroll on drag touch.

The one that comes with flash just won't work.And the Scrollbars are to small.

Anyone know of any components paid or free?>